# Download File with URL Connection

Tags: java

I have following code, it downloads the file, but Adobe says that the file is damage. The file is 74KB big, but I can only download about 27KB. Can you tell me what's wrong. Thanks

```
@WebServlet("/GetData")
public class GetData extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String typ = ".pdf";
    int totalBytesRead = 0;


    String sep = File.separator;
    String saveDir = "C:" + sep + "downloads";
    String link ="/g02pepe/portal?token=9059829732446568452&action_16502593.mainContent_root_cntXYZ_cntShow_actShowFirstRow::km_XXXXXXX-XXXX::=&frontletId=XXXXX";

    String adress = "https://XXXXXXX.XXXX.de/g02pepe/entry?rzid=XC&rzbk=0032&trackid=piwikad277d23c35b4990";
    String together = adress + link;
    String username = "XXXXXXXXX";
    String password = "XXXXXXXXX";
    String authString = username + ":" + password;
    System.out.println("Auth string: " + authString);
    byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
    String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

    try {
        URL url = new URL(adress);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        connection.addRequestProperty("Referer", together);
        System.out.println("Connected to " + together);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.connect();

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        // always check HTTP response code first
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            String contentType = connection.getContentType();
            int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();

            if (disposition != null) {
                // extracts file name from header field
                int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                if (index > 0) {
                    fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                            disposition.length() - 1);
                }
            } else {
                // extracts file name from URL
                fileName = adress.substring(adress.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                        adress.length());
            }
            System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
            System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
            System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
            System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);


            InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

            String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + "Entgeltinformationen"  + typ;             

            // opens an output stream to save into file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                 totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
            }
            System.out.println("Total Bytes read "  + totalBytesRead);

            outputStream.close();
            in.close();

            System.out.println("File downloaded");
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: "
                            + responseCode);
        }

        connection.disconnect();

        out.println("Download done!");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

The file which i want to download is PDF.

Comment: change the downloaded 27kb file's extension to .html or .txt and try to see what is in the file, also tell me if you are behind a proxy or file needs login credentials to download. Probably 27kbs you are downloading is something else, not your file's part.

Comment: When u put the uri  (    "https://XXXXXXX.XXXX.de/g02pepe/entry?rzid=XC&rzbk=0032&trackid=piwikad277d23c35b4990";
)  in a browser works??

Comment: @Darpan i've change the typ of the file to .txt and i can see that the file contains a content. So yes i must authorize to download the pdf.

Comment: @Azimuts If i logged in, and the session is not closed, than i can type the URI to download the file

Comment: what content the downloaded file contains? I faced such error once and problem was that I was not getting authorised and the 27kb like page I was getting was 'authentication error' html page. Check if it is the case with you else we will see to it

Comment: Maybe you can try  to use apache  IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStrem) , it's clearer to manage this than writing byte to byte[ old way ) ]  Also  for the Content Type u can use  Apache Tika to "discover" the content-typ.

Comment: Also Darpan's comment it can be helpfully....Check  that is not an auth error. The best way edit the file :)

Comment: By the way, to download the pdf file, i must navigate to them after i logged in. So perhaphs this can be important..